# Magento "Cannot send headers" with downloadable products

Tags: php, magento, header

I have a Magento store selling very large (2 - 4 GB) downloadable files. Whenever someone is downloading a file and if they try to continue browsing while the file continues to download, the browser stalls until it times out, throwing this error:

> "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php, line 282"

I have checked and the Download.php file does not contain empty spaces that I can see. Plus, it only happens when someone tries to continue browsing during a download in the same browser. Opening another browser and everything is smooth and fast, so apparently Magento gets stuck with a single connection with the client?

Another symptom: While the download is in progress, clicking anywhere else on the site just stalls, as mentioned above. However if during the not-going-anywhere period I cancel the file download, then the new page loads immediately. Meaning that cancelling the download somehow liberates the browser for other connections.

Environment:

I was originally running the server with mod_fcgi and eaccelerator but it kept timing out during long downloads, even after playing with all the FCGI settings I could find, so it is now running with SuPHP.

Apache 2.2 / cPanel 11.30 / CentOS 5.5 / Dedicated server 4 GB RAM / Magento 1.4.2

If it helps, this is the website: http://store.gmvbodybuilding.com

I promise to save a kitty or plant a tree and name them after whomever helps figure this out!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Magento's using the default file-based PHP session handler, the stall will be due to the session file being locked by the download script. You'd need to issue an explicit `session_write_close()` in  the download script, BEFORE the download starts. That'll free up/unlock the session file and allow the user to browser other pages on the site. Otherwise, each request that comes in while the download is in progress will hang on session_start() that particular script tries to get its own lock on the session file.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh I feel this will lead to a solution!! Although your recommendation is a little bit above my head. First of all, do you recommend then switching to DB sessions instead offile-based?

Comment: OK I've done some research and I believe I should stay with file-based sessions.

(Btw, I am trying to post some code in this comment box but not being too successful)

Comment: Can you please advise where to add the code you kindly recommended? This is the Magento code in Download.php that I believe starts the download. 

`    public function output()
    {
        $handle = $this->_getHandle();
        if ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {
            while ($buffer = $handle->streamRead()) {
                print $buffer;
            }
        }
        elseif ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_URL) {
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                print fgets($handle, 1024);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: DB sessions would also need to be locked, otherwise multiple parallel requests would stomp all over each other's updates. Switching is up to you. Both methods have their good points/bad points.

Comment: `function output() { session_write_close; yada yada yada }`

Comment: Can you please advise where to add the code you kindly recommended? This is the Magento code in Download.php that I believe starts the download. 
  
    public function output()  
      {  
        $handle = $this->_getHandle();  
        if ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {  
           while ($buffer = $handle->streamRead()) {  
             print $buffer;  
           }  
         }  
        elseif ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_URL) {  
           while (!feof($handle)) {  
             print fgets($handle, 1024);  
           }  
         } 
      }

Comment: Sorry for the multiple posts, I am trying to paste code.   :-/

Comment: Don't use comments for large code blocks. it's hard to read because it's all one line. for small snippets it's fine, (and surround the code bit with backticks (`)).

Comment: The code directly in the output() function didn't work but I searched and found where to put it, hope it helps anyone else [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/218245/#t297045). I couldn't have searched for this weren't it for your suggestion, thanks Marc! Now to find a kitty to name after you hehehe!